# Formatting a Field Whenever it's Queried

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, time

I have a Rails app that acts as the back-end for the iPhone app. Whenever a record, let's call it `message`, is created, I format a string coming from the iPhone app into Ruby DateTime that will be saved as a field in the database. The string itself was converted from NSDate on the iPhone side. My problem is I want to convert the DateTime back into a string that can be easily formatted back into NSDate whenever a query is sent for messages. Is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: What's wrong with just using a string, like `2013-04-19 08:00:00`?

Comment: I'm going to eventually write some queries requiring the field to be DateTime to order the messages. Unless Rails does that for me even if the field is a string. Haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 1):

The view idea is not necessarily a bad one, but I might suggest putting a `date_string` attribute on your `Message` model like this:

```
class Message
  def date_string
    date.to_s # or however you want to format it
  end
end
```

Then, when you render your JSON, include `date_string`. I don't know what you're using to render your JSON, but I've had a pretty great experience with [RABL](https://github.com/ccocchi/rabl-rails).

Comment: Side note: I would recommend converting to string instead of NSDate since I don't see it as your Rails app's responsibility to know what kind of apps are going to consume its data. Let the Rails app be agnostic, and let the iOS app convert the generic string to NSDate.

Comment: The big question is then would a string as NSDate register with my Rails app when I want to filter through a query using that field?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is a view.  Create a view in the database to access the table:

```
create view vw_table as
    select <columns that you want>
           <code to convert datetime here> as NSDate
    from t;
```

You can then use the view in the application rather than the table.

Comment: Now I need to figure out how to do that via Rails.

Comment: I believe it's as easy as using a regular table. Just create a model on top of the view the same way you would a table.